# PHP session validation

Tags: php, validation, session

I want to write a script that can only be accessed by an administrator.

This is how I want to do it:

```
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) { //not logged in

    //redirect to homepage
    header("Location: http://domain.com/index.php");
    die();

}

if ($_SESSION['user_level'] != 1337) { //not admin

    //redirect to homepage
    header("Location: http://domain.com/index.php");
    die();

}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { //form is submitted

    //validate the submitted data
    //submit the query

}

//form goes here
```

My question is: Is there a better way of validating this (eg. should all three conditionals be nested) or is this enough?

Cheers,

n1te

Comment: you can use IF ELSEIF ELSE it is more suitable for the situation.

Comment: It wouldnt really matter because you're `die()`ing anyway

Comment: Fair enough, but is there a better way of validating this?

Comment: Make them `functions` as pointed out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's not possible that persons rights will change on the fly (namely: you remove admins right), then this should be enough, although I'd build a function:

```
function IsAdmin() {
    if( !isset($_SESSION['user_level'])){
        return false;
    }

    return ($_SESSION['user_level'] == 1337);
}
```

For the case you'll use extended rights checking in future.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a little tidier... though you may want to run some validation on $_SESSION['user_id'] to ensure that it is an int or whatever datatype you are expecting...

```
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id']) || $_SESSION['user_level'] != 1337) { //not logged in

    //redirect to homepage
    header("Location: http://domain.com/index.php");
    exit(); // NOT DIE :P

}


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { //form is submitted

    //validate the submitted data
    //submit the query

}

//form goes here
```

Comment: use 'is_numeric' maybe to validate the $_SESSION['user_id'] after verifying that it existes, else you will get an unidentified index error

Answer (score 0):

I'd write:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id']) || $_SESSION['user_level'] != 1337) {
    //not logged in/not admin
    //redirect to homepage
    header("Location: http://domain.com/index.php");
    die();
}
```